# Whats wrong with my mongo update query using identifier

Tags: mongodb

I think I have a simple syntax issue with my query, but from what I can see, it matches the Mongo docs. Either that or I have been looking at it so long, I cannot see the obvious. Please let it be something simple. Here is what I have:

```
db.collection.update(
   {_id: myId},
   { $set: { 'data.$[elem].val': newData.newVal },
   { arrayFilters: {[ { $or: [ { 'elem.val' : 'hello' }, { 'elem.val2': 'there' } ] } ]}
)
```

Basically, I want to update the val property of the specific element in the data array IF one of the following is true: `elem.val1 === 'hello'` OR `elem.val2 === 'there'`

Comment: You've extra set of parenthesis for arrayFilters and a missing closing parenthesis for both set and arrayFilters. try `{ arrayFilters: [ { $or: [ { 'elem.val' : 'hello' }, { 'elem.val2': 'there' } ] } ]}` &   `{ $set: { 'data.$[elem].val': newData.newVal }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `{` after `arrayFilters:` change it to:

```
db.collection.update(
   {_id: myId},
   { $set: { 'data.$[elem].val': newData.newVal },
   { arrayFilters: [ { $or: [ { 'elem.val' : 'hello' }, { 'elem.val2': 'there' 
  } ] } ]}
)
```